# Where surjectivity goes in?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X$ be an infinite set with the cofinite topology, and $f: X \to X$ a surjective function. Prove that $f$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}(\{x\})$ is finite for all $x\in X$.

I know that $f$ being onto is essential, otherwise $f$ constant is continuous, but the inverse image of the constant is the whole infinite space.

$\implies :$ Suppose that $f$ is continuous. Given $x\in X$, $X\setminus \{x\}$ is open because $\{x\}$ is finite. By continuity, $f^{-1}(X\setminus \{x\}) = X\setminus f^{-1}(\{x\})$ is open, hence the complement $f^{-1}(\{x\})$ is finite.

$\impliedby :$ Suppose that $f^{-1}(\{x\})$ is finite for all $x\in X$. Let $\Omega$ be open. If $\Omega = \varnothing$ there is nothing to do. Otherwise $X\setminus \Omega$ is finite: $$X\setminus \Omega = \bigcup_{i=1}^n \{x_i\} \implies X\setminus f^{-1}(\Omega) = f^{-1}(X\setminus \Omega) = \bigcup_{i=1}^n f^{-1}(\{x_i\})$$ is a finite union of finite sets, hence finite. So $f^{-1}(\Omega)$ is open and $f$ is continuous.

> **Question:** Where did I use that $f$ is onto? If I didn't, where is the flaw in the proof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first part of your argument, you use the fact that $X \setminus f^{-1}(\{x\})$ is open to imply that $f^{-1}(\{x\})$ is finite.  This implicitly assumes that  $X \setminus f^{-1}(\{x\})$ is nonempty.  If $f$ is allowed to be a constant function (which is not onto), then this assumption fails.

Comment: Oh! You're right. Thanks! And just to be sure, there's nothing similar wrong in the second part?

Comment: It looks fine to me!

Comment: Alright! All good then. ` :) `

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $f\colon X\to Y$ is continuous if and only if the preimage of a closed set is closed. In the cofinite topology it means that the preimage is finite, or the entire space.

But if $f^{-1}(\{x\})$ is closed, and it is the entire space, then $f$ is constant. Therefore $f$ cannot be onto, since $X$ is infinite. And indeed note that you can change the condition in the question from "surjective" to "non-constant", and the proof will work as it does.

Comment: Nice observation! Thanks for pointing.

Comment: It's a very nice question. Where did you find it?

Comment: It is an exercise from these notes (http://www.ime.usp.br/~phmacedo/topo-2015/apostila.pdf). It is in portuguese, though, I translated it here. It is exercise 2.57, in page 24 in case you still want to look.

Comment: Oops, page 24 from the text, which is 23 in the pdf.