# Are there less trivial necessary and sufficient conditions?

Tags: general-topology, alternative-proof

Given an infinite set $X$ with the finite-complement topology, find a necessary and sufficient condition for a map $f:X\to X$ to be continuous.

I came up with the condition that $\lvert f^{-1}(\{x\})\rvert<\infty$ for all $x\in X$.

---

**Edit**: I forgot about the necessity of $f$ being surjective (which makes it a funny coincidence that I mentioned that in my example below).

**Edit2**: surjectivity is too strong; We need a condition like this to be able to argue as follows:

> Assume $f$ is continuous, and that $f^{-1}(\{x\})$ is infinite. Then
>   we consider $f^{-1}(X-\{x\})=X-f^{-1}(\{x\})$, and we need to conclude
>   that this is now not-open (to derive a contradiction).

For this all we need is that $f^{-1}(\{x\})\not=X$, so this condition is enough (and much weaker that surjectivity).

---

However, I always find it annoying about these type of questions that there is always a trivial answer (in this case the condition that $f$ be continuous), so that I find it hard to judge if the answer I've given is not also similarly trivial.

So my question is if there are in a sense 'less trivial' conditions possible here. I realise that this is somewhat subjective, but I hope that people understand what I mean here.

For example an answer that seemingly has less direct connection to the finite-complement topology would be less trivial in my eyes, i.e. something like the condition that $f$ be surjective. This is 'less trivial' since it is at first sight 'less inspired' by the space $X$. To be clear: I don't mean to say that the surjectivety of $f$ is a correct answer, it was just an example.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1230801/where-surjectivity-goes-in/ (perhaps?)

Comment: I think you've found the right condition. To can even state it as "$f$ has finite fibers" to make it sound like a very simple condition (which is good to have).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Tthanks for that link. It seems I've made the same mistake as the OP of that question, since overlooked the surjectivity requirement as well. Also based on the fact that the linked question exists I'm now confident that my answer is oke.

Comment: It doesn't have to be surjective. $f(n)=n+1$ is continuous from $\Bbb N$ to itself in the cofinite topology despite not being surjective.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes you're right, I think the much weaker condition that $f$ is not constant is sufficient

Comment: As I wrote in my answer to the linked question. Constant or non-constant + finite fibers is indeed sufficient and necessary.